How do I unescape HTML entities in a Pandas Series?
This
Estamos com problema de conex&atilde;o na loja Serrana Fortaleza, estamos somente por um link, Embratel. E Dnat criado n&atilde;o esta funcionando precisamos de ajuda por favor.
Must be this:
Estamos com problema de conexão na loja Serrana Fortaleza, estamos somente por um link, Embratel. E Dnat criado não esta funcionando precisamos de ajuda por favor.
import html.parser
import pandas as pd

df_abertura['Descricao'] = df_abertura['Descricao'].apply(lambda x: html.unescape(x))

Output:
Estamos com problema de conex&atilde;o na loja Serrana Fortaleza, estamos somente por um link, Embratel. E Dnat criado n&atilde;o esta funcionando precisamos de ajuda por favor.

I prepared following test
import html
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(["Estamos com problema de conex&atilde;o na loja Serrana Fortaleza, estamos somente por um link, Embratel. E Dnat criado n&atilde;o esta funcionando precisamos de ajuda por favor."])
s2 = s.apply(html.unescape)
print(s2[0])

and got output (using python 3.10.12 and pandas 2.0.1)
Estamos com problema de conexão na loja Serrana Fortaleza, estamos somente por um link, Embratel. E Dnat criado não esta funcionando precisamos de ajuda por favor.

which is compliant with desired output.
